# Video Height Relative to it's Div

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I am trying to make a *call to action* on my website as a video, but I'm having difficulties with this code. The video goes 100% of the screen, but I only want it's max-height to be 600px (the same size of the container.) Not sure what to do.

```
video {
   position: absolute;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);        
}
#vidBG {
    height:600px;   
}


<div id="vidBG">
    <video autoplay muted>
          <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because of the absolute positioning

Comment: what should I change it to?

Comment: Give your `#vidBG` a `position: relative`. Ryan.Hunt is right, because of the absolute position, the element is getting its coordinates and size from its closest relative parent, which, since thats never is defined, ends up being `html`

Comment: position relative didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute;`

CSS:

```
video {
  /* position: absolute; */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#vidBG {
  height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: video becomes distorted